# How to calculate $\frac{\partial \mathrm{logdet}(I+XX^T)}{\partial X}$?

Tags: derivatives

How to calculate $\frac{\partial \mathrm{logdet}(I+XX^T)}{\partial X}$? ($X\in\mathbb{R}^{n\times m}$)

I know that $\frac{\partial \mathrm{logdet}(I+X)}{\partial X}=(I+X)^{-T}$, can we use it?

Comment: Try the chain rule, starting from your second equation with $\log \det (I + U)$ where $U = X X^T$.

Comment: @JohnBarber $\frac{\partial \mathrm{logdet}(I+XX^T)}{\partial XX^T}\frac{\partial  XX^T}{\partial X}$, first derivative is known, but how to differentiate second derivative, which is differentiate matrix by matrix, =2X?

Comment: When in doubt in these types of matrix problems, express everything with indices: $\partial (X X^T) / \partial X$ becomes $\partial \left(\sum_m X_{km}X_{\ell m}\right) / \partial X_{ij}$. Do you know what $\partial X_{km} / \partial X_{ij}$ is?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For typing convenience, define the symmetric matrix
$$\eqalign{A &= I + XX^T}$$
Write the cost function in terms of this matrix.

Then calculate its differential and gradient.
$$\eqalign{
\phi &= \log\det A \\
d\phi &= A^{-T}:dA \\
   &= A^{-T}:(dX\,X^T + X\,dX^T) \\
   &= (A^{-T}+A^{-1}):dX\,X^T \\
   &= 2A^{-1}X:dX \\
\frac{\partial \phi}{\partial X} &= 2A^{-1}X \\
}$$
where a colon has been used to denote the trace/Frobenius product, i.e.
$$\eqalign{A:B = {\rm Tr}(A^TB)}$$
and the cyclic property allows terms in a trace product to be rearranged
$$\eqalign{
A:BC &= BC:A \\&= B:AC^T \\&= A^TB:C^T \\&= etc\\
}$$